# How to get select option in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am try to use Vue.js. I write javascript code like...

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        classes: []
    },
    created: function () {
        var vm = this
        // Fetch API
        fetch(xxx.json)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            vm.classes = data.classes;
        })
    }
});
```

The program will fetch a JSON file first.The JSON format like

```
{
  "classes": [
    {
      "name": "A",
      "students": [
        {
          "name": "Eric",
          "fruit": [
            "apple",
            "banana",
            "orange"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Eickson",
          "fruit": [
            "banana",
            "orange"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "B",
      "students": [
        {
          "name": "Ethan",
          "fruit": [
            "banana",
            "apple"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then put the JSON data into the `data` . Then I want the user can pick the items in each class. And use HTML to draw each class and each student

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAWXD.png)

HTML Code like...

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-3" v-for="class in classes">
            Class name: {{ class.name}}</br>
            <div class="form-group row" v-for="student in cless.students">
                <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2">{{ student.name }}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" :name="class.name+'-'+student.name">
                        <option></option>
                        <option v-for="fruit in class.fruit">{{fruit}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <button type="submit" " class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

I want to use the submit button to get all the selected option.

I tried to put a function in method. And `button` add `@click="submitFunc()` . But I have no idea to do it...

Please help me how to implement it. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Loading JSON? Putting JSON in a select box? Selecting items from the box?

Comment: @Kokodoko I want to selecting items from the box. then organize each student's select and pass it to other APIs.

Comment: add v-model on select box and on submit use that v-modal value and if possible please create fiddle so it's easy to help you

Comment: try like this https://jsfiddle.net/pf8t5byq/1/

Comment: @PrAtikLochawala but I need call API . the API return value is not have array "selectedValue".

Comment: You can map that using computed property

Comment: ok, I learn how to use `v-model` ! Vue.js is so amazing!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple immediate ways.

First, you can take the selected item from the select element by simple adding a method and taking the option natively.

Create a method `submitFunc` in your component's method options, in that method, query the select element.

```
new Vue({
//...
  methods: {
     submitFunc: function(){
          let select = this.$el.querySelector('#mySelect'); //add an id for ease
          let selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

          console.log(selectedOption); //will output the element, you can get the value at this point.
          //do something else
     }

  } 
})
```

Secondly, thanks to @Kokodoko, you can use the Vue's two-way data binding by declaring a `selectedItem` property in the `data` options, attaching it in the `v-model` attribute of the select element, and then accessing it via `submitFunc` method.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        classes: [],
        selectedItem: null //this will be your selected option
    },
    methods:{
        submitFunc: function(){
            const selectedItem = this.selectedItem;

            //do something with selectedItem
        }
    }
});
```

In the template

```
<select v-model="selectedItem">
   <option></option>
   <option v-for="fruit in class.fruit">{{fruit}}</option>
</select>

<button v-on:click="submitFunc">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Sorry to say but this is wrong. You have to use data binding with `{ }` instead of `document.querySelector` in Vue.

Comment: @kokodoko I forgot you can use `this.$el`, which imo is perfectly valid. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: It may work, but you are missing the point of data binding. In Vue, you do not need to query for html elements. Instead, in your template, you can use data binding: `<div>Hello {name}</div>`. Read more here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: @Kokodoko You are absolutely right. I've always taken input the vanilla way in Vue.

Comment: @Kokodoko Edited to include the data binding approach.

Comment: That's much better don't you agree? You can add the button with `<button v-on:click="submitFunc">Submit</button>`. This answer and @PrAtik's jsFiddle should solve this question for the OP

Comment: @AbanaClara Your method will let all the options share one v-model. When Eric select fruit banana. Ethan and Erickson also select banana

Comment: @Eric you will have to use a property for each item in your person array as a v-model instead of a root data property like in my example. You'll have to modify it a teeny bit, but the concept and the approach is all in all the same.